# What is the easiest way to transport piles of bones/corpses undetected?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, necromancy

I’m currently working on a Necromancer Build, one thing I’ve really struggled with is having enough piles of bones/corpses at all times to keep up my undead horde.

So far the best idea I’ve had is to find/buy a portable hole and use this to carry the bones/corpses around. To the best of my knowledge there’s not a set time limit for when a body decays in 5e, would this allow me to stack up on bones/corpses until the volume of the hole was filled and then keep them on me discreetly? I feel like this would be a rather easy way to get around as a Necromancer.

Please point out the flaws in my logic.

Comment: You have two questions in one post, so I’ve voted to hold this as “Too Broad”. You can ask your “bonus” question by just posting a new question.

Comment: Even though the extra question falls under the exact same category and is almost the same question? Only with the corpses being reanimated over not being reanimated?

Comment: That’s only assuming that your portable hole idea *is* the best idea. “How do I discreetly transport bodies for my necromancer” is different from “Can undead be transported in a portable hole without suffocating”, and potentially have completely unrelated answers. We handle that here by requiring multiple related questions to be posted as separate single questions. (Notice that the first answer you have isn’t about portable holes at all. Your bonus question got ignored. That’s why it’s good not just for our site organisation, but also for *you*, to post them separately.)

Comment: Ah I see. Fair enough then. I’ll edit the post to only have a singular question.

Answer (score 6):

#### Keep them alive until they're ready to... harvest

Smuggling bones and corpses is difficult. They're heavy and look suspicious.

Bringing a squad of hired mercenaries with you wherever you go is much more discreet. You've just got a bunch of bodyguards with you. When one dies in battle, raise them as a zombie.

Your mercenaries may find this distasteful, but remind them that when one dies, that person's pay is divided between the surviving mercenaries. When the last mercenary dies, recover all the gold you paid them.

Of course, the simplest way is often to create undead from the bodies of enemies you kill while adventuring. This isn't completely reliable, since you may fight enemies which cannot be made into skeletons or zombies, such as golems, elementals, and existing undead.

Comment: This doesn’t answer my question but I’ll be honest this is a good idea.